# How to handle SVN when a project needs to be parts of 2 different .NET solutions?

Tags: c#, .net, svn

I have been working on a .Net C# solution (A) that includes several projects.
This solution is source-controlled via SVN.

Now I would like to start working on a new solution (B) that will include one of the projects of solution A. This solution B will need to be source-controlled via SVN too.

The most obvious solution would be to create solution B and just include the concerned project.
If I do that, the concerned project will be part of 2 different SVN folders. I suppose that this will create tons of subsequent issues?

An alternate solution could be to remove the project from solution A SVN folder and create a dedicated SVN folder for the project. Then I can update this project code from both solution A and B. Only downside is that when I update solution A (or B), I ll need to commit changes for solution A (or B) and for the project SVN folder. But probably better than the former solution?

Is there any othere option? What are the best practises in this case?

thx for your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice depends on your needs.

Your first idea to:

> create solution B and just include the concerned project

will not create any issue at SVN side: SVN will not know that A and B are sharing a subproject (from now on SS).
So if you can/want to maintain the two SS as different projects you can do it and you will not have any drawback.
On the contrary if you need/want to manage SS as "the same project", you will have to update it manually on your local copy and then commit to SVN every time you make a modification on SS when working on A or B.

If you have to manage SS as "the same project" the best solution is your second one:

> remove the project from solution A SVN folder and create a dedicated SVN folder for the project

In this case the SS code will be really the same and really shared. To help out with checkout, updates and commit you can then create some batch script to be more comfortable...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider packaging the shared project(s) via nuGet packages.

This way you'd have 3 subversion folders (a, b, shared). 
Shared is a solution (with own tests etc.) which (can) output to a NuGet package which you publish to a (local) network folder when needed.

Solutions A and B, will reference the packaged libraries, including their revision control.